# Semantic difference between different pointer syntax in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax, semantics

In C++, is this form `int *p` semantically different than this one `int* p`? Or is this clearly a matter of style?

Now this question may be dumb, but I remember that I had seen somewhere **both** styles being used at the same time, something that led to me to believe that there may be different semantics between those forms.

Comment: `int* p` `int *p` `int * p` `int*p` - all valid all semantically identical

Comment: Note that bjarne answers this in [his faq](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace).

Comment: @JesseGood Oh thanx for that link! I searched the web before asking, and I don't know how I missed that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're the same.

That's tricky sometimes, since

```
int* a, b;
```

defines one pointer and one int. This style makes it more clear:

```
int *a, b;
```

Answer (score 4):

It has the same semantic meaning.
If you are using `const` keyword be aware of the caveats:

`int * conts p;` - const pointer to int versus

`int const * p;` - non const pointer to const int.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, they're the same.

The fact that `int* a, b;` declares one pointer and one integer is one aspect of a wart that manifests in other ways too. E.g.:

```
int* a, f(double), c[42];
```

declares a pointer to `int` called `a`, a function that takes a `double` and returns an `int` called `f`, and an array of 42 `int`s called `c`.  That's because all of these "decorations" (`*`, `()`, `[]`) form part of the C++ grammar called the *declarator*, which is associated with an individual name, rather than with the statement as a whole (which is called a *declaration* in the grammar).